# How do I detect whenever two UIImageView overlap?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have two UIImageViews, one of them is moving from left to right, the other one is touch draggable. iI want NSLog to show up a message on console whenever imagetwo overlaps imageone. How Do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `CGRectIntersectsRect` function to easily test rectangle intersection, provided the UIImageViews share the same superview (more exactly, have the same coordinate space).

Likely you will need to add code like the following:

```
  -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *) touches {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect([imageViewA frame], [imageViewB frame])) {
      NSLog(@"Do something.");
    }
  }
```

to the UIView that hosts both image views, or a similar method that is called whenever the drag is completed.

Comment: If they don't share the same coordinate space: `BOOL intersects = CGRectIntersectRect( viewA.bounds, [ viewA convertRect:viewB.bounds fromView:viewB ] )`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.

```
if (CGRectContainsRect([myImageView1 frame], [myImageView2 frame])) {
        NSLog(@"Overlaped, it's working!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(view1.bounds, view2.bounds));

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0 has become...

```
if (self.image2P.bounds.contains(self.image3P.bounds)) {
    print("Overlaped, it's working!")
}
```