# How to check if an image is within a particular subview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, uiscrollview

I've got several images inside a scrollview and within my normal view. I'd like to check by means of an "if statement" if this image is inside my scrollview or not.

i put my images inside the scroller with:

```
[scroller insertSubview:image belowSubview:self.view];
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate [How do I detect whenever two UIImageView overlap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929747/how-do-i-detect-whenever-two-uiimageview-overlap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[scroller.subviews containsObject:image];
```

?

Comment: Image being a UIImageView, I guess ;)

Comment: Thanks Tovi7 you're answer did the job! :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an image only if it is not added yet you can use tags. Each `UIImageView` should have a unique tag.

```
const int uniqueImageTag = 10001;
image.tag = uniqueImageTag;
if ([scroller viewWithTag:imageTag] == nil) {
    [scroller insertSubview:image belowSubview:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
UIView *parent = [self.imageView superview];
if (parent == scroller) {
    //yep
}
```