# How to detect if a moving imageview touches another imageview

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

I am making a kind of "Stay between the lines" iPhone app with swift, I've got a moving imageview and 2 imageviews representing the lines. How do I detect when the moving imageview hits or touches the line image views?

Comment: This is fit for a Google search. Show us what have you tried. 
Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929747/how-do-i-detect-whenever-two-uiimageview-overlap

Comment: I've kind of searches everywhere, the only thing I could find was the same question but for android, the link you gave me is objective-c and I'm making it in swift. I haven't tried anything yet because I'm sort of new to this. just in learning phase :)

Comment: Isn't the API (functions) the same? I don't know iOS development, neither Swift or ObjC, but it seems equivalent: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html (there's even a language switcher at the top right)

Comment: sounds like a job for [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: it worked with:
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.imageview1.frame, imageview2.frame)){
            
            println("OVERLAP")
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

What about use: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454747-cgrectintersectsrect

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageview1.frame, line1.frame) || (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageview1.frame, line2.frame)) {
    // Apply your logic for when the collide
}
```